# Double integral of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(1-|x|)^2+(1-|y|)^2)}$ on $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

The problem is :
Is $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(1-|x|)^2+(1-|y|)^2}$ Lebesgue integrable on $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ ?

What is the value of $\int\int \frac{xy}{(1-|x|)^2+(1-|y|)^2} dydx $ and $\int\int \frac{xy}{(1-|x|)^2+(1-|y|)^2} dxdy $ ?

I tried to show that $\frac{|x|}{(1-|x|)^2}$ is lebesgue integrable.
(Since $\frac{|xy|}{(1-|x|)^2+(1-|y|)^2} \leq \frac{|x|}{(1-|x|)^2}$)

But it was hard.  Is it really lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Decompose your integral into four integrals and work first on the integral over $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ ; the three other integrals have the same issue (integrability vs. non-integrability)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2234783/305862).

Comment: I've already seen that problem, but the main difference is that the denominator of function goes 0 and f goes to infinity. So the integral is improper. How can we guarantee that infinity minus infinity equals zero?